# How Long is the Shelf Life of Refrigerated Eggless Mayonnaise?

Tags: storage-lifetime, mayonnaise

I have learned to make mayonnaise using only oil, milk, and lemon juice. If I store this in the refrigerator, how long will it remain safe to eat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the recipe here, [Milk Mayonnaise](http://leitesculinaria.com/32983/portuguese-milk-mayonnaise.html) will last about a week in the fridge.